# ngtable explicit filtering by entering value/range of values

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am completely new to Angularjs and have used ngtable in-built filter but it filters only on key up.
I have 2 search options:
1) Filter the data based on the value entered in a text box.
2) Filter the data based on the range of values in two text boxes (from,to).

And the filtering should happen on clicking a button.
The user can enter value in any one of the above 3 text boxes and click submit for the filter to happen.

My HTML Code:

```
    Enter Article Name to search:<input type="text" name="articlename">
    Article number from:<input type="text" name="articlenumfrom">
    Article number to:<input type="text" name="articlenumto">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="doSearch()">
```

My Controller Code:

```
    var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
    controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{articlename: "coffee", articleid: 50}
    {articlename: "tea", articleid: 43},
    {articlename: "biscuit", articleid: 27},
    {articlename: "sugar", articleid: 29},
    {articlename: "salt", articleid: 34},
    {articlename: "apple", articleid: 43},
    {articlename: "banana", articleid: 27},
    {articlename: "orange", articleid: 34}];
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    particleid: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
    });
    });
```